# Can we use Optionals in Android programming?

Tags: java, android, option-type

I have been reading about the Optional type in Java 8. I want to implement in some of my Android code.

But does the Dalvik machine for the latest versions of Android (5.1 and 6) implement everything in Java 8?

I'm still running Java 7 with the Eclipse and Android Studio installed on my computers.

Comment: no! i'm afraid that you cant.

Comment: no +1.you can use JDK 1.8, but seems there are couple years before you can use java 8 APIs. [Android Build Environment](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [StreamSupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) lib which adds support for the new Streams API and as a side effect it has `Optional`.

For gradle use:

```
compile "net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.5.1"
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes. But only on API level 24 / Nougat (in current time of writing).

For pre-Nougat, you may opt to these libraries:

- Options (https://github.com/tomaszpolanski/Options)
- Arrow (https://github.com/android10/arrow)
- StreamSupport (https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport)
- Optional (https://github.com/MrHadiSatrio/Optional)
- Guava (https://github.com/google/guava)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it now or in near future. As you can see in [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio) Android start listing Java 7 as a requirement since Android 5.0 that was released at Nov 2014.
That is 3 years after Java 7 first release, so maybe we can use Java 8 from 2017 ;)

On another note you can use lambda using [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) to support lambda in Android dev which is really nice.