# Is it possible to use Java 8 features Optional and Stream for Android 14 and higher

Tags: java, android, java-8

I would like to use optionals and streams in my current project. I have already a lot of null checks and a lot of loops. Not so far ago, I noticed that there are such convenient classes as Optionals and Streams in Java 8. I would like to use them, but I can't, because minSdk of my project is 14. Is it possible to use Java 8 features Optional and Stream for Android 14 and higher?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: IMO, the [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) / [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) combo appears to be a good start.

Comment: Tropiks. Could you give me a link where can I find that it is off-topic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Now that you have rephrased your question, related on SO are: [Optional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428276/can-we-use-optionals-in-android-programming/38761223), [Streams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854239/stream-method-does-not-work-in-android/37880098) I'm sure you can find more than that.

Answer (score 1):

For lambdas you can use Retrolambda library, or Jack