# using @RequiresApi or change the code to work on all api versions

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app, and I have a method which I want it to return Optional, but it forces me to add the @RequiresApi annotation, But I want the app will work on all the API versions.

So should I just add the annotation or use null or other options.

**Edit:**

this is another example of a code I am using:

```
filteredCustomers.stream()
                    .filter(customer-> customer.getName().contains(constraint))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

and it also forces me to add the annotation. Should i use the filter method or just make a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Optional in android.
It is appeared in Java 8. But old devises on api lower then 24 do not support it.

Possible solutions:

1) Use @NotNull and @Nullable annotations to better understand when your field can be null or not

2) Use libraries mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43318642/10261731)

Comment: But regarding other situations, what should i do? Use the @RequiresApi or writing a "bad" code?